# How to pop up a new window to show a Flash (SWF) file with variables?

Tags: javascript, flash

I have some old JavaScript to pop up a new widow to show Flash (SWF) files that no longer works (see below) Can anyone suggest a solution?

```js
function subWin01(){
    window.open("<embed src='ep1.swf'>", "popwindow","resizable=no,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=640,height=480");
}
function subWin02(){
    window.open("ep2.swf","popwindow","resizable=no,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=640,height=480");
}
function subWin03(){
    window.open("ep3.swf","popwindow","resizable=no,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=640,height=480");
}
function subWin04(){
    window.open("ep4.swf","popwindow","resizable=no,menubar=no,directories=no,status=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,width=640,height=480");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your code to format it as code. What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: The newer browser versions (Firefox, Chrome) do not display the SWF file. It does if use " <embed src="ep1.swf"; border="0" height="300"> in a HTML page, but I don't know how to include the "embed" in the javaScript.

Comment: I tried your sample with <embed src='ep1.swf'> but it gives an error message " cannot find the file. The URL of the popup box appears as " file:///D:/Flash/shows/<embed%20src=ep1.swf'>"

Comment: This is your code, not mine. All I did was add formatting. If you look at the doco for window.open, you'll see that it expects a URL: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asphttps://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Sorry My mistake.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I was testing options, however neither option (with or without the <embed> tag works. The doco for window.open is OK, but the problem appears to be athat a "raw" SWF file will not play in a browser window and I need to include the <embed> tag in the window.open code. Thanks

Comment: @OzFlashman yes Chrome does not open solo `.swf` files (haven't tried recently in FF browser). Not even i-Frame pointing to SWF file. You must always now embed within html.